# Idea of implementing polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract

I'm developing in c++ roguelike RPG game. Now I'm doing system of quests and the idea is that there's abstract class Quest, each new quest(e.g. "Kill rats for guard") is new class and each quest contains some objectives of abstract Objective class that we need to do, one by one. And that's working ok. The problem is that objectives differs each other and e.g.

```
class KillMonstersWhole : public Objective
{
    vector<KillMonster> vector_of_monsters_to_kill;
public:
    virtual void ShowObjectiveStatus();
    virtual void CheckIfConditionsFilled();
    virtual vector<KillMonster> GetMonstersToKill() { return vector_of_monsters_to_kill; }
    virtual vector<KillMonster>::iterator GetBeginOfMonstersToKill() { return vector_of_monsters_to_kill.begin(); }
    virtual vector<KillMonster>::iterator GetEndOfMonstersToKill() { return vector_of_monsters_to_kill.end(); }
    KillMonstersWhole(int amount, KillMonster first, ...);
};
```

That class need some specified functions like GetMonsterToKill() etc. (that's inherited from abstract Objective), but e.g that

```
    class ReachXY : public Objective
{
    int x, y;
    string status_text;
public:     
    virtual void ShowObjectiveStatus();
    virtual void CheckIfConditionsFilled();
    ReachXY(int x, int y, string status_text);
};
```

doesn't need it and i've no idea how get a way to implement it without creating blank functions that don't do anything and that will junk my code. I would like to keep in inheritance from one abstract class, cause it's working good - in class Quest i have just a vector of Objective* objects. I know i could e.g. create vector_of_monsters_to_kill in base Objective class, and then make a nonpure, virtual function in that but ReachXY would take additional, not usable place. When i make that functions non-virtual and put them in KillMonstersWhole class i would lost ability to get that by polymorphic pointers Objective*. Is any clever way to do it? Objective and Quest classes for make everything clear:

```
class Objective
{
protected:
    bool conditions_fullfilled;
    OBJECTIVE_ID id;
public:
    Objective() {}
    bool GetConditionsState() { return conditions_fullfilled; }
    virtual void ShowObjectiveStatus() = 0;
    virtual void CheckIfConditionsFilled() = 0;
    virtual vector<KillMonster> GetMonstersToKill() = 0;
    virtual vector<KillMonster>::iterator GetBeginOfMonstersToKill() = 0;
    virtual vector<KillMonster>::iterator GetEndOfMonstersToKill() = 0;
    virtual OBJECTIVE_ID GetID() { return id; }
    virtual ~Objective() {}
};

class Quest
{
protected:
    string name;
    vector<Objective*> objectives_list;
    vector<Objective*>::iterator quest_state;
public:
    Quest() {}
    vector<Objective*>::iterator GetQuestState() { return quest_state; }
    OBJECTIVE_ID GetQuestStateID();
    vector<Objective*> GetObjectivesList() { return objectives_list; }
    virtual void CheckRaiseQuestState();
    virtual void ShowDescription() = 0;
    virtual ~Quest() {}
};
```

Comment: Polymorphism relies on uniform _interface contracts_.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the higher level classes stupid and use the lower-level classes to do the detailed work. If another class needs to know the status of the quest there should be a very generic interface, like

```
std::string Objective::getStatus()
```

that for the classic Rat-Killing mission would be implemented something like

```
std::string RatKiller::getStatus() 
{
    switch (ratcounter)        
    {
        case 0:
            return "Rodents Of Unusual Size? I KNOW they don't exist. Heh heh heh."
        case 1:
            return "You need to kill 1 more rat!"
        default:
            return "You need to kill " + std::to_string(ratcounter) + " more rats!"
    }
}
```

If the hero's objective is to gather one Bourbon, one Scotch, and one Beer, `getStatus` looks at the hero's inventory, finds bourbon and scotch and returns "Thorogood the Destroyer still requires one beer!"

This way the top level doesn't give a smurf what the objective is, it just displays a string.

I use a string here because it doesn't get much more generic than a string, but you could use a status structure that is common to all.

```
struct status
{
    std::string message;
    double percentComplete;
    std::vector<std::string> othernotes; 
    // more general information here
};
```

If the hero performs an action (eg. kills a monster), pass that information into the objective and the objective will update its internal state accordingly.

```
void RatKiller::updateStatus(Action & actionPerformed)
{
    if (actionPerformed.getActionType() == KilledRat)
    {
        if (ratcounter > 0) 
        {
            ratcounter--;
        }
    }
}
```